# FaceNormalsHelper() does not work with the mesh i created - THREE.js

Tags: three.js

i created a mesh with Three.js. I want to see normals of mesh's faces. Here is my code:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 100, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.set(5, 5, 10);

var geo = new THREE.Geometry();
geo.vertices = [new THREE.Vector3(10,5,0), new THREE.Vector3(5,7,0), new THREE.Vector3(2,1,0), new THREE.Vector3(8,9,0), new THREE.Vector3(9,10,0)];
geo.faces = [ new THREE.Face3(0,1,2), new THREE.Face3(1,0,3), new THREE.Face3(3,0,4)];
var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xff0ff0,  side: THREE.DoubleSide, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors});

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geo, mat);
scene.add(mesh);


var edge = new THREE.EdgesHelper( mesh, 0x00ff00 );
scene.add(edge);

var normal = new THREE.FaceNormalsHelper( mesh, 2, 0x90D9C1, 2 );
scene.add(normal);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Edges helper works great. however FaceNormalsHelper() does not work. I can not see any line on the page. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are creating a custom mesh, you need to calculate the normals.

Try adding this after you create the geometry:

`geo.computeFaceNormals();`

You can see [here](http://codepen.io/guardabrazo/pen/wzGzzY) a basic example with only one face.

Comment: I've added a simple example in the answer too.

Comment: i wrote geo.computeFaceNormals before setting vertices.Yes i am half dumb. Thanks.